# Flask application: "ImportError: No module named _psycopg"

Tags: python, psycopg2

I recently deployed a Flask application to Amazon EC2 instance using SQLAlchemy and PostgreSQL.

These are the dependencies that are listed in the requirements file:

```
click==6.7
Flask==0.12.2
Flask-Login==0.4.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.1
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.9.6
MarkupSafe==1.0
psycopg2==2.7.3.1
SQLAlchemy==1.1.14
Werkzeug==0.12.2
WTForms==2.1
```

The application is deployed on Ubuntu 16.x and Apache 2.4 using a WSGI file. The application works, but I get an error whenever SQLAlchemy is being used to query the database for example.

```
[Mon Oct 16 23:59:54.589811 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 21547:tid 140180069140224] [remote 88.207.196.60:36925]     from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
[Mon Oct 16 23:59:54.589813 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 21547:tid 140180069140224] [remote 88.207.196.60:36925] ImportError: No module named _psycopg
```

Whenever I open a Python console using the same virtual environment as the WSGI deployment, I am able to import the module however...

```
python
from psycopg2 import _psycopg
```

What could cause this problem?

Kind regards,
B.

Comment: Check which Python version you're using on the command line vs. what Apache is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found the solution to this **funky** problem.

I was using Python 3 and a virtual environment. No problems there.

The error was caused due to a bad installation of **mod_wsgi.**

I installed it through:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

But this is wrong! If you want to use Python 3, you **instead** have to install the mod_wsgi specific for Python 3, like this:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

Comment: That should be 'instead have to', not 'also have to'. You can't have both installed at the same time as Apache can only use one or the other, not both.

Answer (score 0):

It is using the correct Python version by the way.

The virtual machine and Python path is configured in Apache (see snippet below). Also, when I surf to pages/routes within the Flask application that don't do anything with SQLAlchemy, a page is served like expected.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess myapp python-home=/usr/bin/python3 python-path=/home/ubuntu/envs/myapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages:/home/ubuntu/apps/myapp user=ubuntu group=ubuntu threads=5
```

Comment: You should not use ``python-path`` to refer to ``site-packages``. The better way is to use ``python-home`` to refer to the virtual environment root. See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: Indeed! Modified the configuration to use python-home correctly now.